# Sorting keys in IOS

Tags: ios, sorting, dictionary, key

I am loading keys in to a pickercontrol in ios.
My problem is that I cant get the keys sorted alphabetically.

With the code it goes from UnSorted: Nordfyn, Svendborg, Nyborg, Langeland, Assens, Kerteminde, Middelfart, Odense, Ærø, Faaborg-Midtfyn, to Sorted: Ærø, Svendborg, Nyborg, Langeland, Kerteminde, Nordfyn, Middelfart, Assens, Odense, Faaborg-Midtfyn.

```
NSBundle *KSbundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *KSplistURL = [KSbundle URLForResource:@"KommunerStedtillæg" 
                           withExtension:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *KSdictionary = [NSDictionary 
                            dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:KSplistURL];


NSArray *KSkeys = [[KSdictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];


NSMutableDictionary *KSnewDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (id key in KSkeys)
    [KSnewDict setObject:[KSdictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];

kommunerKeys = [KSnewDict allKeys];
kommunerValues = [KSnewDict allValues];
```

Comment: Try `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` instead of `compare:`?

Comment: Now I get: Odense, Svendborg, Nyborg, Langeland, Ærø, Assens Middelfart, Kerteminde, Nordfyn, Faaborg-Midtfyn.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if you look at kommunerKeys, but the order of the keys in a Dictionary is undefined (see [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDictionary)). Sorting them before adding won't help you.

Comment: good point. Everyone else (including me!) was distracted by the special characters

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *stringsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 @"string 1",
                                 @"String 21",
                                 @"string 12",
                                 @"String 11",
                                 @"String 02", nil];

static NSStringCompareOptions comparisonOptions = NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSNumericSearch |
        NSWidthInsensitiveSearch | NSForcedOrderingSearch;
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

NSComparator finderSortBlock = ^(id string1, id string2) {

    NSRange string1Range = NSMakeRange(0, [string1 length]);
    return [string1 compare:string2 options:comparisonOptions range:string1Range locale:currentLocale];
};

NSArray *finderSortArray = [stringsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:finderSortBlock];
NSLog(@"finderSortArray: %@", finderSortArray);
```

form here http://www.developers-life.com/sorting-by-block.html

add options which you needed

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for this:

```
 [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Simply comparing is not enough.

Comment: Now I get: Ærø, Svendborg, Nyborg, Langeland, Kerteminde, Nordfyn, Middelfart, Assens, Odense, Faaborg-Midtfyn.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue of special characters in the names? Just to be sure, insert ASCII characters only and see if your array is sorted.